# .net wcf interoperability with RPGLE

Tags: wcf, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I am trying to consume a .NET WCF Service in AS400 using RPGLE. I googled most of the sites but didn't find any relevant information.

Can anyone let me know whether AS400 RPGLE Programming interface is can communicate with .NET WCF Service ?

Any help or reference greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If there is REST support for WCF (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/139787/What-s-the-Difference-between-WCF-and-Web-Services) this may help... http://www.bvstools.com/geturi.html

Comment: To expand a bit on @bvstone's comment: In principle, I think it has to be *possible* for an RPGLE client to consume a WCF service. How *easy* that is might depend on the particular WCF service, just like it would depend for any other Web service. If I'm reading things correctly (I'm no expert; just Googling like anyone else), any given WCF service exposes itself to the world via bindings to various protocols. If the WCF service in question supports a protocol you know how to consume, Bob's your uncle. If it doesn't, then you (or the WCF provider) have more work to do.

Comment: Yes, RPGLE can consume a .NET WCF service. Assuming a common SOAP transaction with an XML payload the RPGLE program needs to: open a socket the service's endpoint, build the SOAP request and transmit it, read/parse the response and finally process the data that was returned.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.
WCF is nothing but a web service. So you can take below steps to communicate with AS400.
1) Form your database connection string and hit the AS400 databse
2) You can write methods for getting values from the database, your AS400 counterpart need to develop stored procedures using RPGLE,    which in turn can be called by you within methods and get the result set as per the logic in stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You should use WSDL2RPG. This is a tool which is provided by IBM and generate RPG Stubs für given WSDL Documents. 
This Stub can be used to call Webservice Methods from within your RPG program.

Example:
Wsdl2ws.sh –o/ifsPath/DirectoryForRPGSource –lrpg –s/qsys.lib/ibmilibrary.lib/YourServiceProgram.srvpgm /URLorFilenameOfWSDLDocument/Docname.wsdl

With this you generate the Stub.